# Extending WebElement with new find methods

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have some custom find methods that I often use instead of WebDriver.findElement and WebDriver.findElements. These methods take a custom locator object that contains both a By locator and a regular expression, and they return the WebElement or WebElements that match the By locator and whose text matches the regular expression.

These have been very useful on numerous occasions, and I'd like to provide the same functionality to WebElement.findElement and WebElement.findElements. I could create a new class that implements the WebElement interface and also contains these new find methods, but I'm confused as to whether that would actually work. After all, when I run against FireFox, the elements the driver returns are FireFoxWebElements. When I run against IE, they are InternetExplorerElements. Both of these implement WebElement, but they're completely unrelated to my custom class that implements WebElement, right? They wouldn't have this extra functionality and they couldn't be treated as my custom class, because they... aren't.

Since WebDriver.findElement(s) is the only "source" of WebElements, that is, it is the fundamental way that WebElements arrive in my code, could I then alter my custom findElement(s) methods (which call WebDriver.findElement(s), ultimately) to return a new custom wrapper for any WebElement which includes my special element.find methods? That way, all the WebElements that arrive in my code will be these custom elements with the extra find methods that I want. Right? If so, what would such a wrapper class look like?

Comment: If you want to extend this this far, I'd think about forking Selenium entirely.

Comment: @Arran There's no need to go that far. Chances are high that you can accomplish the same goal without fully reimplementing everything.

Comment: @JimEvans, point taken, always nice to hear it from one of the dev's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A far cleaner approach would be to subclass the `By` class, and provide custom implementations for `By.findElement()` and `By.findElements()`. The architecture was designed for exactly this type of extensibility. This `By` subclass could then be passed as an argument to the `findElement()` and `findElements()` methods of both `WebDriver` and `WebElement` with no problem.

Alternatively, you could repurpose your custom find methods. If they currently take a `WebDriver` object, consider changing it to take a `SearchContext` argument, which is the interface which both `WebDriver` and `WebElement` extend. `SearchContext` is the actual source for the `findElement()` and `findElements()` methods.

Comment: Subclassing the `By` object sounds like a good plan. Just to make sure I understand - when I call `WebDriver.findElement(By)`, is the actual 'meat' of the `findElement` method in `By.findElement(SearchContext)`? So, all `WebDriver.findElement(By)` and `WebElement.findElement(By)` do is call `By.findElement` using themselves as the `SearchContext`? Thanks very much for the advice.

Comment: Depending on the language binding, yes, that's about the size of it.